# how does border color transparent in css work?

Tags: html, css

I am experimenting styles in CSS and I have this samples with  borders in [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/px56grb7/) , why does transparent only affect right and left and not top and bottom in this  code?

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.large {
  font-size: 2em;
}
div {
  width: 3.5em;
  height: 5em;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 50px 20px;
  border-color: red transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="large"></div>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/border-color

Comment: why for the downvote? does transparent work for right anf left only?

Comment: For complete lack of research...this is basic CSS shorthand you could have found with a basic search.

Comment: Because you've told it to use red border for top and bottom, and transparent for left and right.

Comment: the red affects top and bottom and left and right without transparent, with transparent the right and left is only affected, I just don't get it

Comment: check this out http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_border-color

Comment: I wasn't expecting triangle-like result. Thanks for the links

Answer (score 1):

This is because you have the parameters for border-color. When you have 2 params..the first one is for the TOP and BOTTOM and the second one is for LEFT and RIGHT.

If you have 4 parameters it will be:
1st - top
2nd - right
3rd - bottom
4th - left

In your case the first one is red and it affects top and bottom and the second one is transparent and it affects left and right.

Comment: ohh, ok , was introducing myself with css, got it now, though I wasn't expecting a triangular-like result.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax of css is like this:

border: [top],[right],[bottom],[left];

in border-color: red transparent; you stated that top should be read, right should be transparent, and because the other 2 values are empty, they copy themselves.